# How to detect scratches and marks on an image with Emgu CV

Tags: image, emgucv

I have an image in this link https://imgur.com/a/3N3MIxD, I am trying to detect the scratches and other small regions of high color gradient change to no avail. I have tried to use this code with Emgu Cv but it highlights even regions that arent scratches or defects. I have a cylinder and I print images on computer to that cylinder, I am trying to identify the defects on the image coming from that cylinder.

```
await Task.Run(() => {

         using(var image = new MagickImage(imageFiles[0])) {

         //compute the edges with a radius of 10

         image.Edge(10);

         image.GaussianBlur(10);

         image.Enhance();

         image.Write("temp.png");

         //emgu cv takes it from here

         Image<Bgr, byte> mage = new Image<Bgr, byte>("temp.png");

         Mat gray = mage.Convert<Gray, byte>().Mat;

         Mat canny = new();

         CvInvoke.Canny(gray, canny,100,100);    

         VectorOfVectorOfPoint ctrs = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

         Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

         List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>(); 

         //detect the contours

         CvInvoke.FindContours(canny, ctrs, hierarchy, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

         for(int i=0;i<ctrs.Size;i++) {

             //check if the contour is enclosed

             VectorOfPoint res = new();

             CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(ctrs[i], res, 0.2, true);

             double area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(ctrs[i]);

             if(res.Size == 4)

             {

                 if (area > 1500 && area < 2000)

                 {

                     rectangles.Add(CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(ctrs[i]));

                 }

             }

         

         }

         foreach(var rec in rectangles)

         {

            mage.Draw(rec, new Bgr(Color.Chartreuse), 5);

         }

           canny.Save("temp.png");

         }
```